# How can I add Icons or pictures to items on ListActivity in Xamarin.Android.

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to add either a tick or cross, depending on the state of my objects properties. This is my code in a MainActivity that passses list over using intent:

```
Button callHistoryButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ScanHistoryButton);
            callHistoryButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ScanHistoryActivity));
                intent.PutStringArrayListExtra("Codes", codes);
                StartActivity(intent);
            };
```

This is my code in my ListActivity:

```
public class ScanHistoryActivity : ListActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        var codes = Intent.Extras.GetStringArrayList("Codes");
        codes.ToList();
        ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemChecked, codes);
    }
}
```

This is the Object i created:

```
[DataContract]
public class Scan
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ScanValue { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

So if an objects success property is true i want to display a green tick in ScanhistoryActivity and red cross if false. I dont want people to be able to select or deselect manually.

Is a list activity suitable for this?

Comment: so r u using same native code in xamarin?

Comment: yea i think so? what do you mean?

Comment: ok, my simple question is can u use adapters in xamarin? i m aware of cordova so suggesting in that point of view

Comment: yea for sure, it works as it is now, I just want to mark items when the success property is set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your own custom Adapter for this to work.

Also you have to create a layout in order to populate with the adapter the list with data (the layout of each row for example).

For example:

AdapterRow.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
<ImageView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#ff997eff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/BusinessImageView" />
```

Adapter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Linq;

using Android.App;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace testProject
{
public class SomeAdapter : BaseAdapter<Staff>
{
    private readonly List<Staff> _list;
    private readonly Activity _context;
    public int position;


    public SomeAdapter (Activity context, List<Staff> list)
    {
        _context = context;
        _list = list;
    }

    public List<Staff> GetList()
    {
        return _list;
    } 

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return _list.Count; }
    }

    public override Staff this[int position]
    {
        get { return _list[position]; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.adapterRow, null);
        }

        ImageView img1 = view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.BusinessImageView);
        CheckBox chk  = view.FindViewById<CheckBox> (Resource.Id.checkBox1);
//Do aything you want with the data here using _list[position]

        return view;

    }

}
```

}

And this is how to populate the listview with the adapter

```
_ListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListView);
_ListView .ItemClick += _ListView_OnItemClick;
_staffList = new List<Staff>();
_staffList = //Fill it with data
var adapter = new SomeAdapter (this, _staffList);
_ListView.Adapter = adapter;
adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

And to check or uncheck the tick:

```
private void _ListView_OnItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            CheckBox chk = e.View.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);
            if (chk.Checked == true)
            {
                chk.Checked = false;

            }
            else
            {
                chk.Checked = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: can i do it with a simplelistitemchecked list, with the nice green ticks but make them not clickable and only change when property changes??

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview's_appearance/

Comment: Here is the xml code of what you asked, https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_checked.xml with this you have the same appearance, you can alter the adapter or the OnClick to do whatever you want, im not sure when you want them to be clicked

Comment: Thanks, I'm struggling with this! I dont want the list items to be clickable, just want them to display the checked "tick icon" if their success property = success: something like; if(theScan.success == "SENT SUCCESSFULLY"
{
itemchecked = true;
}

--- i have made the success property a string now

Comment: set in everything that you dont want to be clickable the properties `focusable`, `focusableintouchmode` and `clickable` to false and try again. you can do that in the axml also for example in the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            var codes = Intent.Extras.GetStringArrayList("Codes");

```
        codes.ToList();
        ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemChecked, codes);
        ListView lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Android.Resource.Id.List);
        lv.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Multiple;
        lv.Clickable = false;

        //CheckBox chk = lv.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);         
        foreach (var c in codes)
        {
            if (c.Contains("SENT SUCCESSFULLY"))
            {
                int postion = codes.IndexOf(c);
                lv.SetItemChecked(postion, true);
                lv.Clickable = false;
            }
        }
    }
```